# Property 'list' does not exist on type 'void' React - Material UI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm using Material UI with React Typescript and I get the error on .list "Property 'list' does not exist on type 'void'" when I'm using makeStyles and createStyles to remove some padding. So it seems like styles doesn't return anything? I have not been able to solve this, any idea how to solve this?

```
const classes = useStyles();

    const styles = makeStyles(() => {
        createStyles({
          list: {
            padding: "0",
          },
        });
      });
    
    <Menu
                  id="basic-menu"
                  anchorEl={anchorElProfil}
                  open={openProfil}
                  onClose={handleCloseProfil}
                  MenuListProps={{
                    "aria-labelledby": "profil-button",
                  }}
                  sx={{
                    top: "16px",
                  }}
                  classes={{ list: classes.list }}
                  
                >
```

Comment: where do you get/define classes?

Comment: It´s defined like this in the same file 
const classes = useStyles();

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the values returned by createStyles thus resulting in a void. See the [MUI docs](https://mui.com/system/styles/api/#examples-2) for more information.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.red,
    },
  }),
);
```

or in your case:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => {
  return createStyles({
    root: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.red,
    },
  });
});
```